# Create bootable windows 10 USB from chrome OS

Tags: windows-10, usb, bootable-media, chromebook, google-chrome-os

So my PC crashed a couple days ago and I need to run a clean install of windows 10 from a bootable USB. The only other computer I have to work with is a Chrome OS, and I can't seem to find clear instructions on how to create a bootable USB from Chrome OS. Most of my search results are pulling up how to create a bootable USB to use within the Chromebook itself, whereas I want it to be used on a PC. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Find the Microsoft Media Creation Link , load that up in a browser window, go to the Second link (the link below Upgrade this PC) and create a bootable USB from the ISO file. Use that to repair your computer.

Comment: @Steve UEFI will detect your USB drive ONLY if it is formatted as FAT32. (some PC's MIGHT allow NTFS, but FAT32 is recommended). [see here](https://www.quora.com/Why-can-a-UEFI-system-boot-only-from-FAT32-not-NTFS)  and also, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive?view=windows-11)

Comment: This [procedure](https://www.androidphonesoft.com/blog/how-to-make-a-bootable-usb-windows-10-on-chromebook/) is similar but seems more complete than the one in the answer. It might work better.

Comment: @harrymc, the procedure doesn't differ greatly. None of the detail would make a difference, as when I insert the completed USB drive into a Windows machine, Windows says "You need to format the disk before you can use it", so it looks like 1NN is correct. Cheers.

Comment: @1NN, when I added the boot thumb drive I made on Chromebook to a replacement Windows laptop, Windows said the drive needed to be formated, so it looks like you're right. If you can create an answer on how to create a FAT32 Windows installer USB thumb drive on Chromebook, I'll grant you the bounty.

Comment: @Steve sorry I don't know enough about chromebooks to write a concise answer. But there is an [elaborate tutorial](https://gist.github.com/dragon788/26921410d8de054366188c5c5435ae01) I have found. Or, I'd try to copy the steps [from the Windows helppage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive?view=windows-11) but I wouldn't know how to split the file into 4GB chunks on a chromebook

Comment: @harrymc if you want to write an answer, feel free to do so, I wont

Comment: The Chromebook might not be the best tool here. If you have a large-enough Linux boot media to contain the Windows ISO and another USB disk, boot Linux Live on the PC and use it to create the Windows boot on the other USB, rather than using the Chromebook.

Answer (score 6):

Download the ISO file for Windows 10 from the Microsoft website [here](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10). Add the Chrome extension "Chromebook Recovery Utility." [(Click here)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromebook-recovery-utili/jndclpdbaamdhonoechobihbbiimdgai) Rename the downloaded file from `filename.iso` to `filename.bin`(The file name is usually called "Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso"). Launch Chromebook Recovery Utility and click the settings button in the top right corner, select "Use local image". Select the `filename.bin` that you downloaded and renamed. Insert and select the USB drive you are putting the iso on, wait for it to load, your done!

Answer (score 1):

The Chromebook might not be the best tool here, but you do have a PC
that can be used for this, even if its installed Windows is unusable
and needs to be reinstalled.

If your PC has the capacity to connect two USB devices, and you do
have two large-enough USB disks, then use one disk for booting an
operating system that can create on the other disk
the required Windows installation from the ISO.

You would need to copy the ISO to to the boot disk for it to be
available.

You could use either of the following two boot medias :

- A Linux Live USB
- [Tiny10](https://archive.org/details/tiny-10-NTDEV),
  which is a Live lightweight version of Windows 10 for low-end PCs.

References :

- [How to Create a Bootable Windows 10 USB in Linux](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-create-windows-bootable-usb-linux/)
- [How to Create Bootable USB Flash Drive to Install Windows 10 from](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Thanks Harry, but this isn't really a canonical answer.

Comment: @Steve: What's a canonical answer ?

Comment: The closest to an offical answer to `Create bootable windows 10 USB from chrome OS` you can give.

Comment: @Steve: I added canonical references for both boot environments.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write directly ISO to pendrive: from console in Chrome (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) you run command `dd` and write the iso to pendrive device in `/dev/`:

`dd if=./Windows.iso of=/dev/sdb` - change `sdb` to pendrive device (whole)

That way iso written is mostly capable to boot in modern systems.